# Problem with reordering a nested x-axis with ggh4x package

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested, boxplot, ggh4x

I am using the package `ggh4x` and the following set and code to create a boxplot with a nested relation between two categorical variables.

**Data used**

```
set1 <- structure(list(Tx = c("Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", 
"Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
"Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", 
"Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
"Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
"Exposed", "Exposed"), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Species1", "Species2"), class = "factor"), Size = c(88.5, 
83.3, 59.5, 78, 50.3, 57, 78.2, 59, 85, 59.5, 13.1, 50.1, 55, 
60.1, 13.8, 27, 57.1, 53.1, 42, 16, 88.8, 26.2, 62, 108.5, 92.3, 
74.4, 77.3, 96, 88.7, 77.8, 50.7, 61.9, 65.1, 63.5, 64, 88.6, 
53.8, 82.1, 78.8, 75.6)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Nested boxplot**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(set1, aes(x=interaction(Tx, Species), y=Size)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar", width = 0.15) +
  geom_boxplot(show.legend=FALSE, outlier.shape = NA, aes(fill = interaction(Tx, Species))) +               
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, shape=21, colour="black", fill="grey95", stroke=0.5, size=1) +
  guides(x="axis_nested") +
  theme_classic() +   
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold"), 
        text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 12.5))
```

[image]
Right now, the nested relation is displayed on the x-axis just like I wanted. However, the order of the groups is alphabetically, and I'd like to select it myself (with the "Not Exposed" group before "Exposed").

I tried doing it with `weave_factors()` instead of `interaction()`, but then the plot doesn't display the nested relation correctly.

Is there an existing method to selectively reorder the groups ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 99.9% of questions related to the (re-)ordering of axes, facets or legends the answer is always the same:

> Convert your variable()s to `factor`(s) with the order of the `levels` set according to the desired order.

While there is an option to achieve your desired result using `weave_factors`, it depends on the order of the data (and some additional changes, see below), and hence I think the more robust approach to make `Not Exposed` the first category  is to use

```
set1$Tx <- factor(set1$Tx, levels = c("Not Exposed", "Exposed"))
```

or `relevel` as in the answer by @StephanLaurent or depending on the desired order one of the several convenience functions in the `forcats` package.

However, when doing so you have to use `interaction` to get the desired nested axis (as in all examples in the docs, see `?guide_axis_nested`).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

set1$Tx <- factor(set1$Tx, levels = c("Not Exposed", "Exposed"))

ggplot(set1, aes(x = interaction(Tx, Species), y = Size)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.15) +
  geom_boxplot(
    show.legend = FALSE, outlier.shape = NA,
    aes(fill = interaction(Tx, Species))
  ) +
  geom_jitter(
    width = 0.1, shape = 21, colour = "black",
    fill = "grey95", stroke = 0.5, size = 1
  ) +
  guides(x = "axis_nested") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 12.5)
  )
```

[image]

However, for your (example) data and accounting for how `weave_factors` works and differs from `interaction` (see below) you could actually achieve your desired result without converting to a factor by switching the order in which you pass `Species` and `Tx` to `weave_factors` and by using the more verbose `guide_axis_nested()` with `inv=TRUE`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

# Just to ensure that Tx is a non-factor 
set1$Tx <- as.character(set1$Tx)

ggplot(set1, aes(x = weave_factors(Species, Tx), y = Size)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.15) +
  geom_boxplot(
    show.legend = FALSE, outlier.shape = NA,
    aes(fill = weave_factors(Species, Tx))
  ) +
  geom_jitter(
    width = 0.1, shape = 21, colour = "black",
    fill = "grey95", stroke = 0.5, size = 1
  ) +
  guides(x = guide_axis_nested(inv = TRUE)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 12.5)
  )
```

[image]

###### `weave_factors` vs. `interaction`:

`weave_factors` differs from `interaction` in two respects (see `? weave_factors`:

1. it *orders the new levels such that the levels of the first input variable is given priority over the second input*.
2. it *treats non-factor inputs as if their levels were `unique(as.character(x))`*, i.e. the levels are set in the order as in the data (similar to what `forcats::fct_inorder` does)

For that reason `weave_factors` gives IMHO a more natural ordering of the levels of the combined factors

```
weave_factors(set1$Tx, set1$Species) |> levels()
#> [1] "Not Exposed.Species1" "Not Exposed.Species2" "Exposed.Species1"    
#> [4] "Exposed.Species2"
```

i.e. the levels of combined factor are "ordered" first by the first input, then the second whereas with `interaction` it's the other way around:

```
interaction(set1$Tx, set1$Species) |> levels()
#> [1] "Not Exposed.Species1" "Exposed.Species1"     "Not Exposed.Species2"
#> [4] "Exposed.Species2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert `set1$Tx` to a factor and then set `"Not Exposed"` as the first level:

```r
set1$Tx <- relevel(factor(set1$Tx), ref = "Not Exposed")
```