# Using mutate (dplyr) to modify values of a column, while preserving groups order

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggh4x

I use this dataset and code to create a nested boxplot in which the groups are reordered, following the method suggested on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77617469/problem-with-reordering-a-nested-x-axis-with-ggh4x-package :

```
set1 <- structure(list(Tx = c("Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", 
"Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
"Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", 
"Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
"Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
"Exposed", "Exposed"), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Species1", "Species2"), class = "factor"), Size = c(88.5, 
83.3, 59.5, 78, 50.3, 57, 78.2, 59, 85, 59.5, 13.1, 50.1, 55, 
60.1, 13.8, 27, 57.1, 53.1, 42, 16, 88.8, 26.2, 62, 108.5, 92.3, 
74.4, 77.3, 96, 88.7, 77.8, 50.7, 61.9, 65.1, 63.5, 64, 88.6, 
53.8, 82.1, 78.8, 75.6)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

set1 <- set1 %>%
  mutate(w=mean(Size), max = max(Size), .by = c(Tx, Species))

set1$Tx <- factor(set1$Tx, levels = c("Not Exposed", "Exposed"))

set1 <- set1 %>%
  mutate(Tx = paste0(Tx, '\n(n = ', n(), ')'), .by = c(Tx, Species)) 

ggplot(set1, aes(x=interaction(Tx, Species), y=Size)) +
  geom_boxplot() +               
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, stroke=0.5, size=2) +
  guides(x = "axis_nested") +
  theme_classic()
```

The following code usually allows me to add the number of observations (n = ...) on each axis ticks.
`set1 <- set1 %>% mutate(Tx = paste0(Tx, '\n(n = ', n(), ')'), .by = c(Tx, Species))`

However when used after `set1$Tx <- factor(set1$Tx, levels = c("Not Exposed", "Exposed"))`, the groups are no longer reordered correctly ("Exposed" comes before "Not exposed" in the nested x-axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create "Tx (n)" (using `set1 <- set1 %>% mutate(Tx = paste0(Tx, '\n(n = ', n(), ')'), .by = c(Tx, Species))`) the variable type changes from `factor` to `character`; if "Tx (n)" is a factor you don't lose your desired order, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggh4x)

set1 <- structure(list(Tx = c("Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", 
                              "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
                              "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", 
                              "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
                              "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
                              "Exposed", "Exposed"), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Species1", "Species2"), class = "factor"), Size = c(88.5, 
                                                                                                                                                            83.3, 59.5, 78, 50.3, 57, 78.2, 59, 85, 59.5, 13.1, 50.1, 55, 
                                                                                                                                                            60.1, 13.8, 27, 57.1, 53.1, 42, 16, 88.8, 26.2, 62, 108.5, 92.3, 
                                                                                                                                                            74.4, 77.3, 96, 88.7, 77.8, 50.7, 61.9, 65.1, 63.5, 64, 88.6, 
                                                                                                                                                            53.8, 82.1, 78.8, 75.6)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "tbl", "data.frame"))

set1 <- set1 %>%
  mutate(w=mean(Size), max = max(Size), .by = c(Tx, Species))

set1$Tx <- factor(set1$Tx, levels = c("Not Exposed", "Exposed"),
                  ordered = TRUE)

set1 <- set1 %>%
  mutate(Tx = factor(paste0(Tx, '\n(n = ', n(), ')')), .by = c(Tx, Species))

ggplot(set1, aes(x=interaction(Tx, Species), y=Size)) +
  geom_boxplot() +               
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, stroke=0.5, size=2) +
  guides(x = "axis_nested") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

If you want to specify the order, you need to specify the factor levels for the "Tx (n)" variable, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggh4x)

set1 <- structure(list(Tx = c("Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", 
                              "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
                              "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", 
                              "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Not Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
                              "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
                              "Exposed", "Exposed"), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Species1", "Species2"), class = "factor"), Size = c(88.5, 
                                                                                                                                                            83.3, 59.5, 78, 50.3, 57, 78.2, 59, 85, 59.5, 13.1, 50.1, 55, 
                                                                                                                                                            60.1, 13.8, 27, 57.1, 53.1, 42, 16, 88.8, 26.2, 62, 108.5, 92.3, 
                                                                                                                                                            74.4, 77.3, 96, 88.7, 77.8, 50.7, 61.9, 65.1, 63.5, 64, 88.6, 
                                                                                                                                                            53.8, 82.1, 78.8, 75.6)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "tbl", "data.frame"))

set1 <- set1 %>%
  mutate(w=mean(Size), max = max(Size), .by = c(Tx, Species))

set1$Tx <- factor(set1$Tx, levels = c("Not Exposed", "Exposed"),
                  ordered = TRUE)

set1 <- set1 %>%
  mutate(Tx = factor(paste0(Tx, '\n(n = ', n(), ')'),
                     levels = c(paste0("Not Exposed", '\n(n = ', n(), ')'),
                                paste0("Exposed", '\n(n = ', n(), ')'))),
                                .by = c(Tx, Species))

ggplot(set1, aes(x=interaction(Tx, Species), y=Size)) +
  geom_boxplot() +               
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, stroke=0.5, size=2) +
  guides(x = "axis_nested") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I did the exact code you showed here and the order remains the same...

Comment: In fact, the tick marks for Species  are in the right order, but it's not the case for Species2.

Comment: I finally made it work. I don't exactly know why, but it did work out by replacing `.by =` by `group_by()`. Thank you !